# Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Hi I have something problem with nginx. When I get restarted nginx I take this error in log and nginx does not start

```
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2414 20243/7f20bba00700 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:532 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2415 20243/7f20c14cf780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:901 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2415 20243/7f20bb1ff700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2415 20243/7f20bb1ff700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2416 20243/7f20bba00700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 128 spare client objects
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2416 20243/7f20bba00700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished

[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2421 20248/7f283efa1700 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:422 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2422 20248/7f284488e780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:492 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2422 20248/7f283e7a0700 Ser/Server.h:817 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2422 20248/7f283e7a0700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouterApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2423 20248/7f283efa1700 Ser/Server.h:464 ]: [UstRouter] Shutdown finished
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2424 20248/7f284488e780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:523 ]: Passenger UstRouter shutdown finished
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:34.2623 20243/7f20c14cf780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
2016/10/21 22:59:35 [info] 20285#20285: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:35.2830 20290/7faa66c87780 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:35.2898 20293/7fe1788cd780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:35.2899 20293/7fe1788cd780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:35.2910 20293/7fe1788cd780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 20293
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:35.2985 20298/7fada7533780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2016-10-21 22:59:35.2991 20298/7fada7533780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 20298
```

Comment: this is just an info, not an error and not even a warning. the shared memory for push module is not the reason for your problem.